# A card game that has an ultimate skill for each character

Tags: identify-this-game

I can't really recall what is this board / card game.

I am not sure is it a werewolf, vampire, some other social deduction game, or it's a different one from what I have mentioned.

Each character card will have an ultimate skill. In order to use the skill, you need to reveal your role card.

Anyone can figure out what is this game?

Sorry for the small amount of details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds to me like you are thinking of [Shadow Hunters](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/24068/shadow-hunters). Its got some social deduction aspects to it, and each player has a special ability that they can use by revealing who they are.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's [Citadels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citadels_(card_game)).

Each turn, players get to pick their role cards from a deck of 8 or 9, the King calls each character (Assassin, Mage, King, Priest ...) forward in a fixed order and in your turn, the chosen character card grants certain abilities and advantages. Some of these characters have a color that can correspond to the color of buildings you own, generating extra income.

During one turn, depending on the number of players, you could get to pick two characters and effectively have two turns-in-one.

Comment: In Citidels you reveal your role as part of the game when it comes around to your turn not in order to use an ability.

Comment: Thanks for your help steenbergh though it's not what I wanted to find. =)